# Best way to split data into few lines?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I have data as shown:
2021    43466.822   medium variant

2021    43510.982   high variant

2021    43416.407   low variant

2021    43468.429   constant fertility

2021    43580.45    instant replacement

And need to get chart:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/eBKqmOUsSa_6PBlomh5Erg.png

I have tried the transform fold option, but it does not help me. And making a lot of layers for that - will be a lot of code. Is there any smart way? Also I will need an legend like the one shown.

```
    vegalite({
      height:300,
      autosize: "fit",
      width:width,
      title: {text:"Ukraine Population Prospects",
              subtitle:"Total population, million"
             },
      data: {
              url:"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/turiy/005f2ce11637fefcde8e9d6efdb0c2e6/raw/19e67bb3a6d63e7fd9f49a596e5d24404469bd63/population_prospects.csv"},
      transform: [{"calculate": "datum.population/1000", "as": "population"},{fold:["medium variant","high variant", "low variant", "constant fertility","instant replacement", "momentum", "zero migration", "constant mortality", "no change"]}],
      layer: [
        { mark: "line",
          encoding:{      
            "x": {
              "timeUnit": "utcyear",
              "field": "year",
              "type": "temporal",
              "axis": {
                "values":[1950,1991,2020,2100],
                "domain": false,
                "gridDash": {"value": [1,1]}
              }
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "population",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": [15,55]},
              "axis": {
                "domain": false ,
                "gridDash": {"value": [1,1]}
              }
            }
          },
          color: {"value":"#0000ff"},
          transform:[{filter:{"timeUnit": "utcyear", "field": "year", "range": [1950, 2020]}}]
        },
        {
          mark: "line",legend:{title:"low variant"},
          encoding:{      
            x: {
              "timeUnit": "utcyear",
              "field": "year",
              "type": "temporal",
              "axis": {
                "values":[1950,1991,2020,2100],
                "domain": false,
                "gridDash": {"value": [1,1]}}
            },
            y: {
              "field": "population",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": [15,55]},
              "axis": {
                "domain": false ,
                "gridDash": {"value": [1,1]}
              }
            },
            legends:{
              "orient": "top-right",
              "stroke": "color",
              "title": "Origin",
              "encode": {
             "symbols": {
              "update": {
                "fill": {"value": ""},
                "strokeWidth": {"value": 2},
                "size": {"value": 64}
              }
            }
          }
            },
            color: {"field": "key", "type":"nominal"}

          },    
          transform:[{filter:{"timeUnit": "year", "field": "year", "range": [2020, 2100]}},
                     {filter:{field:"type", "equal":"low variant"}}]
         }


      ]})
```

And I am getting like this https://image.prntscr.com/image/3Y9WNk4SQzGYWDr2JKWV9A.png

Comment: The links you posted do not work. Can you update?

Answer (score 0):

If your variants are listed by name in a column as in your example dataset, you can use a detail encoding to split them into different lines ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSBXATgGxSgAt54AHAZ2QHpqBzASwvgDpH4isAjLCgUxwBjAPYA7eH3EsRAW2rxcDAJ7UADKoCsAMwBMgvgEYDANgDMAdi18tg6HwAcfAJzRj16F1WCdfY9RywAO7UBk6+5lxcprDGrqZ8ltBOWgAsTrAaTm4a0DopKar5xk5ccdRkwmRYeAgMYgD6ZDjCFGR8gvAU0hQAbpDgYAC+ADQDkDKwOADWhJB4DKJ8kKOYkiLQC3SE6BgwfIgMBKjAkPBKbbOiwjILsATDUFoMfHjQs2cXIwOYAB7bp+clqhIABHLCwcQMRDwBg9JYPSBPF5vYFKPiTSBfDBQJT-D5AqBgiEw6Gw+GPZ6vWYVKo1GFiTEDQYgQZAA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/turiy/005f2ce11637fefcde8e9d6efdb0c2e6/raw/19e67bb3a6d63e7fd9f49a596e5d24404469bd63/population_prospects.csv"
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "detail": {"type": "nominal", "field": "type"},
    "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "year"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "population"}
  }
}
```

[image]

If you use `color` rather than `detail`, each line will be a different color and a legend will be included.

To add labels at the right side of the chart, you can use a text mark with an aggregate transform; something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/turiy/005f2ce11637fefcde8e9d6efdb0c2e6/raw/19e67bb3a6d63e7fd9f49a596e5d24404469bd63/population_prospects.csv"
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "detail": {"type": "nominal", "field": "type"},
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "year"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "population"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"filter": "datum.type != 'estimate'"},
        {
          "aggregate": [{"op": "argmax", "field": "year", "as": "rightmost"}],
          "groupby": ["type"]
        }
      ],
      "mark": {"type": "text", "align": "left"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"type": "nominal", "field": "rightmost.type"},
        "x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "rightmost.year"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "rightmost.population"}
      }
    }
  ],
  "width": 400
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I add al these legends?

Comment: If you use a color encoding, each line will be a different color and a legend will be added.

Comment: I will need the subscription right in the right to the line.

Comment: It's not great practice to ask for multiple things in a single question. In the future, please consider posting a followup question if you're asking about a different concept. For now, I've edited my answer.

Comment: any ideas how to make them not intersect?

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to keep them from intersecting currently is to adjust their position manually, or to export your chart and use https://github.com/vega/vega-label. In the near future, vega-label will be wrapped into vega/vega-lite, at which point automatic label adjustment will be possible within Altair.

Comment: How can I add legends for two columns there?"estimate" and "projection

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean